# Print structure of a data type by its type

Tags: haskell

I want to parse a JSON file into a data type and print an error in case of parsing error along with the expected data structure.

Let's take an example data record:

```hs
data Foo = {
  bar :: String
}
```

I want to print the structure of this data into console when it fails to parse, to show the user what structure the JSON should be. Also, I don't want to hardcode the structure into the error log, to make it typesafe (in a meaning: when I add a new field to the data, it should be printed in case of parse error, too. When it would be hardcoded I would forget to modify the string about the structure to be printed).

It can be easily printed to console when I have a value of this data by simply having the `deriving Show` on the `Foo`. But how to print the structure without a value?

It is enough if I would be able to print the type definition literally. But if you have a nice type safe solution that could be nicely formatted it is surely welcome :)

Comment: Using  the reflection primitives of `Data.Data` one should be able to print all the constructors of a type and the type of their arguments. You'll need `deriving Data` on the type. This might already be available in some library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure there are multiple ways to do this, but I've used generics. If you aren't familiar with generics, you should read the documentation of [GHC.Generics](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/GHC-Generics.html#v:MetaData).

First, some language extensions and imports:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

import GHC.Generics
import GHC.TypeLits ( KnownSymbol, symbolVal )
import Data.Proxy ( Proxy(..) )
import Data.Typeable (typeRep, Typeable)
```

Using the `DefaultSignatures` extension along with `DeriveGeneric`, we can create a typeclass `PrintStructure` that automatically implements the `printStructure` function for you. All you need to do is pass in a `Proxy` with a [phantom variable](https://wiki.haskell.org/Phantom_type) of type `WhateverYouWantToPrint`.

```
class PrintStructure a where
    printStructure :: Proxy a -> String
    default printStructure :: (Generic a, PrintStructure' (Rep a)) => Proxy a -> String
    printStructure _ = printStructure' (Proxy :: Proxy (Rep a p))
```

`PrintStucture'` is a class that prints the structure of types using their `Generic` representation.

```
class PrintStructure' a where
    printStructure' :: Proxy (a p) -> String
```

Now, the next part isn't going to make sense unless you have read the documentation, so please do that first. (Generics aren't as complicated as they appear).
Implementing `PrintStructure'` for void and unit types:

```
-- Empty string, there's nothing to print for them
instance PrintStructure' V1 where
    printStructure' _ = ""

instance PrintStructure' U1 where
    printStructure' _ = ""
```

Constructors:

```
instance ( PrintStructure' f
         , KnownSymbol name
         ) => PrintStructure' (C1 ('MetaCons name fx sl) f) where
    printStructure' _ = symbolVal (Proxy @name)
                     ++ " { " 
                     ++ printStructure' (Proxy :: Proxy (f p)) 
                     ++ " }"
```

Record selectors:

```
instance ( KnownSymbol name
         , PrintStructure' f
         ) => PrintStructure' (S1 ('MetaSel ('Just name) su ss ds) f) where
    printStructure' _ = symbolVal (Proxy @name) ++ " :: " ++ printStructure' (Proxy :: Proxy (f p))
```

Sums, products, constructor fields and data types:

```
instance ( PrintStructure' f
         , PrintStructure' g
         ) => PrintStructure' (f :*: g) where
    printStructure' _ = printStructure' (Proxy :: Proxy (f p))
                     ++ ", "
                     ++ printStructure' (Proxy :: Proxy (g p))

instance ( PrintStructure' f
         , PrintStructure' g
         ) => PrintStructure' (f :+: g) where
    printStructure' _ = printStructure' (Proxy :: Proxy (f p))
                     ++ " | "
                     ++ printStructure' (Proxy :: Proxy (g p))

instance ( PrintStructure' f
         ) => PrintStructure' (S1 ('MetaSel 'Nothing su ss ds) f) where
    printStructure' _ = printStructure' (Proxy :: Proxy (f p))

instance (Typeable t) => PrintStructure' (Rec0 t) where
    printStructure' _ = show (typeRep (Proxy @t))

instance ( KnownSymbol name
         , PrintStructure' f
         ) => PrintStructure' (D1 ('MetaData name mod pkg nt) f) where
    printStructure' _ = "data "
                     ++ symbolVal (Proxy @name)
                     ++ " = "
                     ++ printStructure' (Proxy :: Proxy (f p))
```

Now we can test it out.

```
λ> data Foo = Bar { p :: String, q :: Int } | Baz { r :: Bool } | Qux () Int deriving (Show, Generic)

λ> instance PrintStructure Foo

λ> putStrLn $ printStructure (Proxy :: Proxy Foo)
data Foo = Bar { p :: [Char], q :: Int } | Baz { r :: Bool } | Qux { (), Int }
```

And it works! As you can see, the formatting isn't the best, but pretty printing shouldn't be much of a problem.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction to the Generics. I was avoiding generics in haskell for now but I have a motivation now :)

Comment: Yes, you will have trouble avoiding generics for this task because it is literally "print the metadata for this type".